# Is there a infinite dimensional topological vector space with the weight of topology larger than the algebraical dimension?

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, functional-analysis, set-theory, topological-vector-spaces

A topological vector space is a vector space endowed with a topology such that the sum of vectors and the multiplication by scalars are continuous.

The weight of the topology $\tau$ is the smallest cardinal $\alpha$ such that there is a basis $\mathcal B$ of cardinality $\alpha$ for $\tau$.

By algebraical dimension, I mean the classical cardinality of its Hamel basis.
So, my question is: is there some infinite dimensional topological vector space $V$ such that the weight of $V$ is larger than the dimension of $V$?

If useful, I'm okay with using some axioms such as the Continuum Hypothesis. To give some context, my interest in this question arose from a theorem that holds if the weight of the topology is less than or equal to the dimension. So, I want to know if there are counterexamples if the weight is greater than the dimension, which includes knowing whether there are spaces with this property.

Comment: I added a couple tags to increase the likelihood that someone who can answer will see the question, hope you don't mind!

Comment: I'm not understanding this apparently. $\Bbb R$ is a TVS whose topological weight is $\aleph_0$, but is $1$ dimensional as a vector space.

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti thanks!

Comment: @PaulSinclair. It was my fault. The title of the question asks for an infinite dimensional vector space, but I accidentally omitted this part of the text. This question is indeed trivial in finite dimensional spaces. I have already added the necessary information.

Comment: Are you concerned with just TVS over $\Bbb C$ or $\Bbb R$, or do you allow other topological fields?

Comment: @PaulSinclair, at first I'm thinking in TVS over $\mathbb C$ and $\mathbb R$ , but I think any example would be at least enlightening.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider $\mathbb{R}^\infty$, a countable-dimensional vector space with the colimit topology with respect to its finite-dimensional subspaces (that is, a subset is open iff its intersection with each finite-dimensional subspace is open).  I claim that $\mathbb{R}^\infty$ is not first-countable and thus has uncountable weight.

To prove this, let $(e_n)$ be a basis for $\mathbb{R}^\infty$ and suppose $(U_n)$ is any countable family of neighborhoods of $0$.  For each $n\in\mathbb{N}$, choose $r_n\neq0$ such that $r_n e_n\in U_n$ (such an $r_n$ must exist since $U$ is a neighborhood of $0$), and let $C=\{r_ne_n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}.$ Any finite-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^\infty$ contains only finitely many points of $C$, and thus $C$ is closed.  So $\mathbb{R}^\infty\setminus C$ is a neighborhood of $0$ which does not contain any $U_n$, showing that $(U_n)$ is not a neighborhood base at $0$.

(By the way, the fact that $\mathbb{R}^\infty$ is even a topological vector space at all is nontrivial.  To prove the continuity of scalar multiplication and addition, you need to show that $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}^\infty$ and $\mathbb{R}^\infty\times\mathbb{R}^\infty$ also have the colimit topology with respect to their finite-dimensional subspaces.  This follows from Theorem A.6 in Hatcher's *Algebraic Topology*, for instance.)

Comment: It's a very clever construction. I was really hoping for some explicit example rather than only existence guarantees, but a familiar space with a manageable topology is excellent for what I need. Do you have references for other examples like this?

Comment: I've never heard of this space being used in functional analysis or anything like that (as anything other than a counterexample).  It comes up very naturally in algebraic topology though--it is in some sense the "right" notion of "infinite-dimensional Euclidean space" for use in algebraic topology, being just a formal limit of finite-dimensional spaces.

Comment: More generally algebraic topology deals with tons of spaces that are built as colimits of finite-dimensional pieces in order to have useful homotopical properties, and these spaces have some unusual pointset-topological properties compared to the more familiar "geometric" spaces like manifolds.  For more about spaces like this you might look up things like the theory of CW-complexes.