# A topological vector space with cardinality smaller than the weight of topology

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, functional-analysis, set-theory, topological-vector-spaces

A topological vector space is a vector space endowed with a topology such that the sum of vectors and the multiplication by scalars are continuous.

The weight of the topology τ is the smallest cardinal α such that there is a basis B of cardinality α for τ.

In that setting, my question is: is there an infinite-dimensional topological vector space $V$ over $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$ such that the weight of $V$ is larger than the cardinality of $V$?

This question is a stronger version of that other [problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4792068/is-there-a-infinite-dimensional-topological-vector-space-with-the-weight-of-topo). For a topological vector space $V$ over $\mathbb R$ ou $\mathbb C$, if $dim(V)\geq\mathfrak c$, then the cardinality of $V$ is equal to his dimension. So, any answer for the original problem with dimension at least $\mathfrak c$ is also a solution for the present question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is:

We need the following

**Lemma.** There is a Tychonoff (in fact, paracompact) topology on $\mathfrak c$, such that its weight $w(\mathfrak c) > \mathfrak c$.

This is certainly well-known, and there are many ways to proof it. One way is the following:
Instead of $\mathfrak c$, we define it on
$\mathfrak c \cup \{\infty\}$:
Let $\mathfrak F$ be a $\mathfrak c$-uniform ultrafilter on $\mathfrak c$. Define the topology such that each $\alpha \in \mathfrak c$ is isolated and the neighborhoods of $\infty$ are the sets $F \cup \{\infty\}$, $F \in \mathfrak F$.
It is easy to see that this topology is as required.
(Note that this is a subspace of the Stone-Cech compactification of the discrete space of cardinality $\mathfrak c$.)

Now consider the free topological vector space
$V(\mathfrak c)$ over $\mathfrak c$ as defined
[here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0166864117301657).
Then $V(\mathfrak c)$ is a Hausdorff topological vector space over $\mathbb R$ with the subspace $\mathfrak c$, and $\mathfrak c$ is a vector space basis (Theorem 2.3). Hence
$|V(\mathfrak c)| = \mathfrak c$. Moreover, $w(V(\mathfrak c)) \ge w(\mathfrak c) > \mathfrak c$.